# Format specifier for 'long long'

Tags: c

I declare a variable for a 64 bit counter as :

```
long long call_count;
```

What is the format specifier that I should use in print statements?

I tried, `%l`, `%ld`, `%ll`. None seems to be correct.

I use Diab C compiler for compiling my application code to run on pSOS operating system.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

According to C99, it should be "%lld" (see, for example,[here](http://www.nullstone.com/download/releasenotes-ns-c.htm)).  If Diab C isn't C99, then you'd have to look at the compiler docs, which I can't seem to find online with a quick Googling.

Comment: For 'long long unsigned int' you should use "%llu"

Answer (score 17):

It's `"%lli"` (or equivalently `"%lld"`)

Answer (score 12):

Microsoft and Watcom use `%I64d` (capital eye), others use `%lld` (lowercase ell ell).

Comment: "use %I64d (capital I)": try again?

Comment: Microsoft uses ll (ell ell) for long long; I64 (eye) for __int64. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx

Comment: The format specifiers are less ambiguous when they are in `fixed width` (provided a sane fixed-width font is used).

Answer (score 6):

This one and even little more has been described here:
[cross-platform printing of 64-bit integers with printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299083/cross-platform-printing-of-64-bit-integers-with-printf)

TL;DR:
You can use PRId64 macro (from inttypes.h) to print 64 bit integers in decimal in a semi-portable way. There are also other macros (like PRIx64).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe %lld? I think this is the format for gcc, don't know anything about Diab C compiler.

Comment: %lld is the Standard conversion specifier for long long, Windows is the only one I am aware of that doesn't support this (but they don't support a lot of standards).  Also, this is specific to the standard c library being used, not the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

It is %lld for signed and %llu for unsigned

Answer (score 1):

```
long long t1;             //signed
unsigned long long t2;    //unsigned

printf("%lld",t1);
printf("%llu",t2);
```