# cross-platform printing of 64-bit integers with printf

Tags: c, printf

In Windows, it is "%I64d". In Linux and Solaris, it is "%lld".
If I want to write cross-platform `printfs` that prints `long long` values: what is good way of doing so ?

```
long long ll;
printf(???, ll);
```

Comment: Apparently I need #if defined(WIN32) && !defined(PRId64 ) \n #define PRId64 "I64d" \n #endif. Thanks everybody who answered.

Comment: you should also look into your types and have a `typedef` to replace `[u]int64_t` if they are not available.

Comment: what's the difference between 64 bit integer and long? I am reading other's program and they use PRId64, which I don't understand.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches.

You could write your code in C99-conforming fashion, and then supply system-specific hacks when the compiler-writers let you down. (Sadly, that's rather common in C99.)

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

printf("My value is %10" PRId64 "\n", some_64_bit_expression);
```

If one of your target systems has neglected to implement `<inttypes.h>` or has in some other way fiendishly slacked off because some of the type features are optional, then you just need a system-specific `#define` for `PRId64` (or whatever) on that system.

The other approach is to pick something that's currently always implemented as 64-bits and is supported by printf, and then cast. Not perfect but it will often do:

```
printf("My value is %10lld\n", (long long)some_64_bit_expression);
```

Comment: You didn't say the exact type you were printing, but as others have noted, `PRId64` is specifically for `int64_t`.  If you use `<stdint.h>` there is supposed to be a corresponding `<inttypes.h>` macro for printf.

Comment: I would like to accept both answers, DigitalRoss's and Random832's, don't know how to do it. Files request on meta forum.

Comment: Late comment, but I missed that I still needed the `%` in the string before the `PRId64`, or else it complained about `some_64_bit_expression` being unexpected: `printf("Foo %" PRId64, some_64_bit_expression);`

Answer (score 2):

MSVC supports `long long` and `ll` starting [Visual Studio 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

You could check the value of the [`_MSC_VER` macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) (`>= 1400` for 2005), or simply don't support older compilers.

It doesn't provide the C99 macros, so you will have to cast to `long long` rather than using `PRId64`.

This won't help if you're using older MSVC libraries with a non-MSVC compiler (I think mingw, at least, provides its own version of printf that supports `ll`)

Comment: Looks like MS added the `ll` modifier support to msvcrt.dll (at least on my Win7 box). I'm surprised by this. It doesn't look like MinGW did anything special to support it (and last time I tried using `ll` with MinGW it failed miserably).

Comment: Thanks. I never knew that MSVC supported %lld.

Comment: I would like to accept both answers, DigitalRoss's and Random832's, don't know how to do it. Files request on meta forum.

Answer (score 1):

No on linux and solaris it is only incidentally that this is `lld` for a 64bit type. C99 prescribes simple (but ugly) macros to make these things portable `PRId64`. Since some windows compilers don't follow the standard you might be out of luck, there, unfortunately.

**Edit:** In your example you are using a different thing than a 64bit integer, namely a `long long`. This could well be 128 on some architectures. Here C99 has `typedef`s that guarantee you the minimum or exact width of the type (if they are implemented on the platform). These types are found with the `inttypes.h` header, namely `int64_t` for a fixe-width 64 bit type represented in two's complement. Maybe or maybe not your windows compiler has this.

Comment: Note: The `PRId64` macro is for printing `int64_t`, not `long long`.

Comment: @Dietrich, exactly. I interpreted the title of the question as such. But you are right, I add a comment about long long.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative you can use code like this:

```
uint64_t currentTimeMs = ...;

printf("currentTimeMs = 0x%08x%08x\n",
            (uint32_t)(currentTimeMs >> 32),
            (uint32_t)(currentTimeMs & 0xFFFFFFFF)
    );
```

Or maybe:

```
printf("currentTimeMs = %u%09u\n",
            (uint32_t)(currentTimeMs / 1000000000),
            (uint32_t)(currentTimeMs % 1000000000)
    );
```

Comment: "%u%09u" will unfortunately format 16 as 000000016, which might look as an octal number at worst and weird at best.