# cross platform printing 64-bit intergers through a customized printf function

Tags: c++

There is a debug class that is used to print out debug statements based on a level. The higher the level, the more detailed messages you would get. The problem occurs when I am trying to do print out a uint64_t. On different platforms using printf style it could be either %li or %lli. I want it to become portable. However, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299083/cross-platform-printing-of-64-bit-integers-with-printf), I could include a PRId64 and it would adjust accordingly. The problem is because my messages are customized, it takes in a const char *. I am unable to do with with a message such as `"Calling based on pts %"PRId64, mv.pts` because it is expecting a char * where there isn't one. What are other approaches in solving this?

Inside the main code

```
#include "debug.h"
#include <inttypes.h>    

#define P_DBG(level, format, ...) DBGPRINT(level, ("%-5d%s::%s() - " format "\n", __LINE__, str().c_str    (), __FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__))
#define P_ALL(format, ...) P_DBG(P_ALWAYS, format, __VA_ARGS__)
class Something 
{
    Something::Print(uint64_t a) {
        P_ALL("Calling based on %"PRId64 "\n", a)
}
```

Inside debug.h

```
class vdebugPrint {
class vdebugPrint(int ID, int level) : v_id(ID), v_level(level) {}
int Print(const char* formatString, ...) __attribute__((__format(printf,2,3)));
}
...
#define VPRINT3(level, msg)    VdebugPrint(ID, level).Print msg
#define PRINT(level, msg)     VPRINT##level(level,msg)
#define DBGPRINT(level, msg)     PRINT(level,msg)
...
```

Inside debug.cpp

```
...
VdebugPrint::Print(const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list argumentList;
    va_start(argumentList, formatString);
    vprintf(formatString, argumentList);
    va_end(argumentList);
}
```

The exact error message is

```
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘PRId64’
     AV_TRACE("Calling based on %"PRId64"\n", mv.pts);
                                  ^
/.../debug.h:140:94: note: in definition of macro ‘VPRINT3’
 #define VPRINT3(level, msg)      VdebugPrint(ID, level).DebugPrint msg

/.../debug.h:146:45: note: in expansion of macro ‘DBGPRINT’
 #define DBGPRINT(level, msg)            PRINT(level, msg)
                                         ^
/.../file.h:54:41: note: in expansion of macro ‘DBGPRINT’
#define P_PBD(level, format, args...)  DBGPRINT(level, ("%-5d%s::%s() - " format "\n", __LINE__, str().c_str(), __FUNCTION__, ##args))
```

EDIT:

I've attempted Olaf suggestion to no avail. Here is what I've done. Everything else is the same except for the main code.

```
...
class Something
{
    Something::Print(uint64_t a) {
        const char* message = "Calling based on %";
        size_t mlen = strlen(message);
        char buf[mlen + strlen(PRId64) + 1];
        strcpy(buf, message);
        strcpy(buf + mlen, PRId64);

        P_ALL(buf, a);
    }
}
```

The error that I get is

```
error: ‘PRId64’ was not declared in this scope
     char buf[mlen + strlen(PRId64) + 1];
                            ^
```

EDIT2: So I fixed the problem with it not finding PRId64. I had to define `__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225567/how-to-print-a-int64-t-type-in-c) before include inttypes. This now solves the problem and it compiles!

Comment: could you post the exact error message?

Comment: Well, `"Calling based on pts %"PRId64, mv.pts"` is incorrect anyway. You need `"Calling based on pts %"PRId64"", mv.pts`, note the `"` has to move.

Comment: @EOF: There is no actual need for the last `""`. `PRI*` uses string literal concatenation. It is just a macro giving the appropriae format string.

Comment: @Olaf: Well, this *is* a bit of a special case, where the conversion specifier is the end of the format string. I was trying to make the point that, in general, the `PRIwhatever` needs to be enclosed in `"`s.

Comment: It seems that this should work, to be honest.. yes, what's the error messages?

Comment: @EOF: That is not correct. They are alread string literals. So no ned to enclose in `"` (that would actually not work). I suppose you mean to insert them into another string literal, _that_ has to be broken into two literals, so the whole tripple would be subject to _string literal concatenation_.

Comment: `class Something` is invalid in C. Did you mean to only tag C++?

Comment: What compiler and switches are you using?  `inttypes.h` may not have been available prior to C++11, and some more recent compilers may only have partial C++11 support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macros defined in `inttypes.h` are string literals with the proper `printf` type specifier. So you have to append this to the format string. Normal usage would be to use *string literal concatenation*.

If your format string is variable, you have to append the specifier to the string:

```
char buf[strlen[format] + strlen[PRId64] + 1];
strcpy(buff, format);
strcat(buff, PRId64);
```

Note this could be optimized using strcpy for both:

```
size_t flen = strlen(format);
char buf[flen + strlen[PRId64] + 1];
strcpy(buff, format);
strcpy(buff + flen, PRId64);
```

**Caution:** The format string has to be NUL-terminated!

**Update:**

The original answer was for C as that was one of the language-tags and the code looked more like C than C++. However, according to comments, you can use this also for C++11 (check your compiler's support), if you `#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS` *before* `#include <inttypes.h>`. (Note the include might appear in other headers, so you should define the macro as early as possibly in your file.)

Comment: It appears as though the macro is not expanding. This is the error I get when I try this. `error: ‘PRId64’ was not declared in this scope
         char buf[mlen + strlen(PRId64) + 1];` I have mad sure that `inttypes.h` is included.  I have edited my code above to show you what I've done.

Comment: @bluestring: As you had the original question tagged C, I did answer according to the standard. That macro is not required by the standard. It is a very bad idea to remove a target language you got an answer for.

Comment: @bluestring: However, I added a note about C++.

Answer (score 0):

You need spaces between the adjacent string literals and the macros for the expansion and concatenation to work.  For example:

```
// Note the space on either side of PRId64
AV_TRACE("Calling based on %" PRId64 "\n", mv.pts);
```

(I don't know if this is required according to the standard, but it is required to make it work for some preprocessors I've used.)